# Exact solution of 2d poisson equation on an annulus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, laplacian

I have to find the exact solution of the following: 
$$-\nabla^{2}{u}=1$$
on the two dimensional domain 
$$\Omega=\{z=(x,y):|z|\ge{1} \wedge |z|\le{R}\} $$
On the boundaries of $\Omega$ we impose dirichlet boundary conditions so basically the problem is the following: 
\begin{align}
-(u_{xx}+u_{yy})=1\quad in\  \Omega\\
u=0\quad on \ \partial\Omega
\end{align}
Now, I have to find the exact solution of this problem. 
I decide to procede as follows:

1. I used polar coordinates (r,$\theta$), therefore my equation turns out to be 
   $$-(u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}u_{\theta\theta})=1$$
2. I made the following assumption: since the data of the problem are radially symmetric, I want to search for a solution which is radially symmetric. Hence, I assume that in polar coordinates, u is a function only of the radius as 
   $$-(u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r})=1$$
3. At this point I can solve it: 
   $$ \frac{1}{r}(ru_{r})_{r}=-1 $$ 
   Integrating we obtain 
   $$ u_{r}=-\frac{r}{2}+\frac{C_{1}}{r}$$
   and integrate another time 
   $$ u=-\frac{r^2}{4}+C_{1}\ln(r)+C_{2}$$
4. Now imposing u(1)=u(R)=0 we get $$C_{1}=\frac{R^{2}-1}{4\ln(R)}$$ and $$C_{2}=1/4$$ and the problem is solved.

Is my procedure entirely correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Correct and well explained.